# Check for duplicates in array of custom type using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Good day all.

Let's say for example I have a custom type:

```
public struct Group {
    public string GroupName;
    public int someInt;
}
```

And say I have an array of this type:

```
public Group[] Groups;
```

I want to check to see if `Groups` has two or more `Group` items with the same `GroupName`. In pseudo-code it would look like:

```
if (Groups has two or more Group items with the same name) {
    // we have a problem
}
```

Will be glad if someone helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check the `IComparable` interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 **or** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Groups.GroupBy(e=>e.GroupName).Count() < Groups.Count)
{
    // we have a problem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked! Have a wonderful day, I love you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
if(Groups.GroupBy(e=>e.GroupName).Count()>1)
{
 //...
}
```

Comment: I really thought this would work but no matter how many Group items in Groups with the same GroupName it always equates to 1. Please check your code and get back to me :(

Comment: Could you add to your question a collection of data you are using to test?

Comment: @Tayab, believe me or not, but this piece of code should works as well!

Comment: @Tayab, now that I see the answer that you marked as  the correct one, I realize what you really needed to know is if there were some repeated groups, I thought you want to check if your list of groups belong to a same group

Comment: @octavioccl No worries, it's probably my fault I didn't explain better. Thanks for the quick answer anyway, you're a good person :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a better solution but, you can try this.

```
var results = (from p in Groups
              group p by p.GroupName into g
              select new { GroupName = g.Key, Total = g.Count 
              }).Where(c=>c.Total>1).ToList();

If(results.Count()>1)
{

}
```